# I need help creating a class to store data for my entire project including user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am still very new to WPF and I've spent a week trying to understand MVVM with not very much luck, but I am not specifically trying to follow those rules, I just need to store information into a class so all of my user controls can access it and also change it. 
This is what I have so far:

```
namespace WpfApplication2.Funtions
{
    public class Binder : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private string _Test_String;
        public string Test_String 
        { 
            get { return _Test_String; }
            set { _Test_String = value; OnPropertyChanged("Test_String"); }
        }

    }
}
```

User control:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    //Funtions.Binder _B = new Funtions.Binder();

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow MW = new MainWindow();
        textBox1.Text = MW._B.Test_String;
    }
}
```

Mainwindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public Funtions.Binder _B = new Funtions.Binder();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _B.Test_String = "HELLO";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _B.Test_String =  "Hello from main";
    }



}
```

I see what is happening here, the user control is creating a new instance of MainWindow so it is NOT the same value, but how do I actually access the same Binder instance that MainWindow created from usercontrol1 so that it can read and change it? or if I can't achieve what I want this way how should I go about doing it? I know there has got to be a very simple solution to this. I don't want to use the project Settings.

Please don't mind the super noob question but I've been stuck for days now, I just need a simple explanation and solution and I'll be on my way. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the instance of your main window, not create a new one as you figured out.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow MW = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    textBox1.Text = MW._B.Test_String;
}
```

Comment: I can't access any public (MainWindow) variables from usercontrol1 using your suggestion. "MW._B.Test_String;" is not recognized, no public variables are, and they aren't suggested in the intellisense.

I am getting:
System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for '_B' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

you should use same instance of main window on usercontrol's  button click . like as follows

```
var mainwindow =Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

and using same instance get value

```
textBox1.Text = mainwindow .Test_String;
```

Comment: I did this but ._B or any other public data in MainWindow isn't recognized. I get:

System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'test' and no extension method 'test' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) //////// test is a public string in MainWindow